# Symfony 1.4, Doctrine (Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY non-multiple)

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I just teach Symfony and Doctrine.
I don't know hot to fetch 1 row array instead of multirow array in Doctrine.
I using this:

```
$q = $this->createQuery('a')
      ->innerJoin('a.Translation t')
      ->andWhere('t.lang = ?', $language)
      ->andWhere('t.name LIKE ?', 'somename%');

    return $q->execute(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_RECORD);
```

And then i get something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [created_at] => 2012-03-19 17:40:52
            [updated_at] => 2012-03-21 17:44:04
            [created_by] => 1
            [updated_by] => 1
            [Translation] => Array
                (
                    [en] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => somename
                            [lang] => en
                            [slug] => somename
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

But i need

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [created_at] => 2012-03-19 17:40:52
            [updated_at] => 2012-03-21 17:44:04
            [created_by] => 1
            [updated_by] => 1
            [id] => 1
            [name] => somename
            [lang] => en
            [slug] => somename
        )

)
```

Some body knows how i can make it?

Comment: Add a fetchOne() instead of execute()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use just

```
$q = $this->createQuery('a')
  ->select('a.id as id, t.name as name')
  ->leftJoin('a.Translation t')
  ->where('t.name LIKE ?', $name.'%')
  ->andWhere('t.lang = ?', $language);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to explicit add a select with columns you need?

```
$q = $this->createQuery('a')
      ->select('a.id, a.created_at, a.updated_at, a.created_by, a.updated_by, t.id, t.name, t.lang, t.slug')
      ->innerJoin('a.Translation t')
      ->andWhere('t.lang = ?', $language)
      ->andWhere('t.name LIKE ?', 'somename%');

return $q->execute(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `WITH` keyword?

```
$q = $this->createQuery('a')
        ->innerJoin('a.Translation t WITH t.lang = ?', $language)
        ->where('t.name LIKE ?', 'somename%');
return $q->execute(NULL, Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```